# android parse json after optimize php json_encode

Tags: android, json

There are Arrays in Arrays:

```
Array 
(
 [0] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [2] => v3 )
 [1] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [3] => v3 )
 [2] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [10] => v3 )
 [4] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [3] => v3 )
)
```

After `json_encode` on andorid I get the following:

```
{
 «0»: [ «v1», «v2», «v3» ],
 «1»: { «0»:«v1», «1»:«v2», «3»:«v3», },
 «2»: { «0»:«v1», «1»:«v2», «10»:«v3» },
 «4»: { «0»:«v1», «1»:«v2», «3»:«v2» }
}

JSONArray jList = jb.getJSONArray(response); //exception is not array
```

Is there a good way to parse this as `Array[Array[]]` on Android?

Comment: can you show us the whole chunk of PHP code that starts with the array as input and ends with the string containing `«`/`»` characters. There's something really odd going on there, but I can't see it from what you've posted.

Comment: I don`t have access to php script. Author show me debug print of array before and after json_encode. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php Sequential array sample

Comment: well, php's `json_decode` won't put those `«`/`»` characters in there, so I'm wondering where they've come from. They're obviously not standard json. Standard json should have `"` characters for the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have non-contiguous indices. If you "renumber" the array with

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

you will have

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [2] => v3 )
    [1] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [3] => v3 )
    [2] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [10] => v3 )
    [3] => Array (  [0] => v1  [1] => v2  [3] => v3 )
)
```

and as a result `json_encode` will create

```
[ ["v1", "v2", "v3"], { "0": "v1", ...}, ... ]
```

If you want to have inner arrays too, you must ensure that the inner arrays have contiguous indices as well.

If you can't change the PHP code, the only way is to parse this as a JSON object and iterate over the properties using [`keys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) and pick the values individually.

Comment: I can only parse result on android. php script can`t change.

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov But your colleague can fix his code. If not, you must parse as an object, please see updated answer.

Comment: There is no reason to change php script. This is default way in php json_encode on sequential array. I seek way for small coding in android. Top level array is JSSONObject second level JSONArray [0], JSSONObject [1], JSSONObject [2], JSSONObject [4]. But if chage fourth element from [4] to [3] json_encode optimize and top level Array be a JSONArray